Transferring HEVC video stream from Java server to Android client
There is a client and a server. The server sends screenshots to the client. I need to make the server transmit a video stream in HEVC format. On Android this video stream must be decrypted. How can I do that? I will attach a server file that sends desktop screenshots and client files. But in general I need help, I need to complete this task, otherwise I'm finished.
Server
package filesharing;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avcodec;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.*;


public class Screenshot {

    public void sendScreenshot(final ObjectOutputStream out) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            FrameGrabber grabber = null;
            FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = null;
            try {
                Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
                grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0); // 0 для захвата рабочего стола
                grabber.setFormat("gdigrab");
                grabber.setImageWidth(screenRect.width);
                grabber.setImageHeight(screenRect.height);
                grabber.start();

                recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(out, screenRect.width, screenRect.height);
                recorder.setFormat("hevc");
                recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_HEVC);
                recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
                recorder.start();

                Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

                org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame frame; // Используем Frame из org.bytedeco.javacv
                int totalBytesSent = 0; // Счетчик общего количества байт, отправленных на сервер
                while ((frame = grabber.grab()) != null) {
                    BufferedImage image = converter.getBufferedImage(frame);
                    org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame convertedFrame = converter.convert(image);
                    recorder.record(convertedFrame);

                    // Подсчет количества байт, отправленных в каждом кадре
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteOutputStream);
                    int frameBytesSent = byteOutputStream.size();
                    totalBytesSent += frameBytesSent;

                    // Вывод лога с информацией о количестве отправленных байт в текущем кадре
                    System.out.println("Sent " + frameBytesSent + " bytes in the current frame.");
                }

                // Вывод общего количества отправленных байт после завершения отправки
                System.out.println("Total bytes sent: " + totalBytesSent);
            } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (grabber != null) {
                        grabber.stop();
                    }
                    if (recorder != null) {
                        recorder.stop();
                    }
                } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception | FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

//Client
//1 file
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.AndroidFrameConverter;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

public abstract class UpdateScreenshot extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Frame> {
    private static final String TAG = "UpdateScreenshot";
    private ImageView imageView;

    public UpdateScreenshot(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Frame doInBackground(byte[]... videoBytes) {
        try {
            // Проверяем, есть ли данные видеопотока
            if (videoBytes.length > 0 && videoBytes[0] != null) {
                // Создаем ByteArrayInputStream с использованием массива байтов данных видеопотока
                ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(videoBytes[0]);

                // Создаем FFmpegFrameGrabber, используя ByteArrayInputStream
                FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(inputStream);
                grabber.setFormat("hevc");
                grabber.start();

                // Читаем следующий кадр
                Frame frame = grabber.grab();

                // Выводим размер кадра в логи
                if (frame != null) {
                    int frameSizeBytes = calculateFrameSizeBytes(frame); // Метод calculateFrameSizeBytes() должен быть реализован в вашем коде
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received frame size: " + frameSizeBytes + " bytes");
                }

                return frame;
            } else {
                // Если нет данных видеопотока, возвращаем null
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Frame frame) {
        if (frame != null) {
            // Преобразуем кадр в изображение и отображаем его на ImageView
            AndroidFrameConverter converter = new AndroidFrameConverter();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(converter.convert(frame));
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Frame is null in onPostExecute");
        }
    }

    private int calculateFrameSizeBytes(Frame frame) {
        // Оценка размера кадра в байтах
        int width = frame.imageWidth;
        int height = frame.imageHeight;
        int bitsPerPixel = 24; // Для простоты предполагаем формат RGB24
        int bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / 8;
        return width * height * bytesPerPixel;
    }

}

//2 file,
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import me.varunon9.remotecontrolpc.MainActivity;
import me.varunon9.remotecontrolpc.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LiveScreenFragment extends Fragment {

    private int xCord, yCord, initX, initY;
    boolean mouseMoved = false, moultiTouch = false;
    private ImageView screenshotImageView;
    private Timer timer;
    private int screenshotImageViewX, screenshotImageViewY;
    long currentPressTime, lastPressTime;

    public LiveScreenFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_live_screen, container, false);
        screenshotImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.screenshotImageView);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = screenshotImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                screenshotImageViewX = screenshotImageView.getHeight();
                screenshotImageViewY = screenshotImageView.getWidth();
                ViewTreeObserver obs = screenshotImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
        screenshotImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MainActivity.clientSocket != null) {
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            xCord = screenshotImageViewX - (int) event.getY();
                            yCord = (int) event.getX();
                            initX = xCord;
                            initY = yCord;
                            MainActivity.sendMessageToServer("MOUSE_MOVE_LIVE");
                            //send mouse movement to server by adjusting coordinates
                            MainActivity.sendMessageToServer((float) xCord / screenshotImageViewX);
                            MainActivity.sendMessageToServer((float) yCord / screenshotImageViewY);
                            mouseMoved = false;
                            /*startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            clickCount++;*/
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (!moultiTouch) {
                                xCord = screenshotImageViewX - (int) event.getY();
                                yCord = (int) event.getX();
                                if ((xCord - initX) != 0 && (yCord - initY) != 0) {
                                    initX = xCord;
                                    initY = yCord;
                                    MainActivity.sendMessageToServer("MOUSE_MOVE_LIVE");
                                    //send mouse movement to server by adjusting coordinates
                                    MainActivity.sendMessageToServer((float) xCord / screenshotImageViewX);
                                    MainActivity.sendMessageToServer((float) yCord / screenshotImageViewY);
                                    mouseMoved = true;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            // supporting only single click
                            currentPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            long interval = currentPressTime - lastPressTime;
                            if (interval >= 500 && !mouseMoved) {
                                MainActivity.sendMessageToServer("LEFT_CLICK");
                                delayedUpdateScreenshot();
                            }
                            lastPressTime = currentPressTime;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        timer = new Timer();
        updateScreenshot();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.live_screen));
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private void updateScreenshot() {
        if (MainActivity.clientSocket != null) {
            MainActivity.sendMessageToServer("SCREENSHOT_REQUEST");
            new UpdateScreenshot(screenshotImageView) {
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Frame frame) {
                    super.onPostExecute(frame);
                    // Здесь вы можете выполнить любые дополнительные действия с кадром,
                    // если это необходимо перед отображением на ImageView
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    }

    private void delayedUpdateScreenshot() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateScreenshot();
            }
        }, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}

It also provides the ability to control a remote server by tapping on the phone screen. I didn’t make this database, but I need to modify it so that the client receives a hevc video stream and displays it on the screen, as you already understand, this is a remote desktop application. Knowledgeable people, please help me.
I tried to use various libraries, but apparently my knowledge of Java is not enough.
